# postgresql join tbale and sum before 12 month

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables
A table:

```
|customer_ID |receipt_timestamp|cost       |
|------------|-----------------|-----------|
|1416229     |2021-09-01       |39.99      |
|1416229     |2021-08-05       |30.00      |
|1416229     |2021-07-03       |59.00      |
|1416229     |2020-10-05       |177.00     |
|1416229     |2020-05-19       |162.00     |
|1416229     |2019-06-26       |61.00      |
|1416229     |2019-02-26       |150.00     |
|1416229     |2018-05-10       |45.00      |
|1416229     |2018-01-09       |58.00      |
|1416229     |2018-01-08       |323.00     |
```

B table:

```
|customer_ID      |review_date   |customer_level |
|-----------------|--------------|---------------|
|1416229          |2018-01-15    |1              |
|1416229          |2019-01-15    |0              |
|1416229          |2020-10-15    |1              |
```

how can I join these two tables and calculate the sum of the cost from 12 months before the `review_date` in table B.

Expected Results like this:

```
|review_date |customer_level   |12 month cost at review|
|------------|-----------------|-----------------------|
|2018-01-15  |1                |381.00                 |
|2019-01-15  |0                |45.00                  |
|2020-10-15  |1                |339.00                 |
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing could be solved with a join and some time based joins.

Let me first recreate your case (btw next time it would be better to define table structures and insert statements so people can quickly replicate your dataset)

Your **Table A** (named `test_cust` in my example)

```
create table test_cust (customer_id int, receipt_timestamp date, cost float);


insert into test_cust values (1416229,'2021-09-01',39.99 );
insert into test_cust values (1416229,'2021-08-05',30.00 );
insert into test_cust values (1416229,'2021-07-03',59.00 );
insert into test_cust values (1416229,'2020-10-05',177.00);
insert into test_cust values (1416229,'2020-05-19',162.00);
insert into test_cust values (1416229,'2019-06-26',61.00 );
insert into test_cust values (1416229,'2019-02-26',150.00);
insert into test_cust values (1416229,'2018-05-10',45.00 );
insert into test_cust values (1416229,'2018-01-09',58.00 );
insert into test_cust values (1416229,'2018-01-08',323.00);
```

And your **Table B** (named `test_rev` in my example)

```
create table test_rev (customer_id int, review_date date, customer_level int);
insert into test_rev values (1416229,'2018-01-15',1);
insert into test_rev values (1416229,'2019-01-15',0);
insert into test_rev values (1416229,'2020-10-15',1);
```

Now what you need to do is to `JOIN` the two via the `customer_id` field and the timestamps like

```
select 
    review_date,
    customer_level,
    sum(cost) total_cost
from test_cust c
join test_rev r
on c.customer_id=r.customer_id
and c.receipt_timestamp > r.review_date - interval '12 month'
and c.receipt_timestamp <= r.review_date 
group by
    review_date,
    customer_level;
```

Check the temporal join using:

- `c.receipt_timestamp > r.review_date - interval '12 month'` to go back 12 months from the `review_date`
- `c.receipt_timestamp <= r.review_date` to exclude receipts with future timestamps (compared to the `review_date`)